# Iterating grib tools over a folder of grib files

Tags: batch-file, grib, grib-api

I am attempting to mass-convert a large number of GRIB files to netCDF using grib tools (I am on Windows 7) in a batch file.

I am using this code:

```
for /f %%f in (`dir /b O:\Praksa\incadata\2014\01\01`) 
   do 
     echo %%f grib_to_netcdf -D NC_FLOAT -o *.nc *.grb
```

But when I run it nothing seems to happen except for CMD opening and closing really fast.

There is probably some syntax error I missed in there, but my main question is: Can I use wildcards (*) in grib tools statements? 
Also, are spaces in directory pathnames problematic?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the backticks around the `dir` command to single-quotes `'` as documented. Add a `pause` instruction on the next line to hold the window open, or preferably run from the command prompt, don't click a batch.

Answer (score 1):

You got the syntax wrong. `cmd` is very picky about syntax. Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f %%A in ('dir /b /a-d z:\*') do (
     echo %%~fA grib_to_netcdf -D NC_FLOAT -o %%~dpnA.nc %%~dpnA.grb
)
```

`%%~fA` gives you the full qualified filename, `%~dpnA` the **D**rive, **P**ath and **N**ame only. See `for /?` for those modifiers. `dir /a-d` excludes foldernames. See `dir /?` for more info.